# c bitwise negation conversion question

Tags: c, casting, bit-manipulation

the following code:

```
signed char sc = ~0xFC;
unsigned char uc = ~0xFC;
```

when compiled gives me the following warnings:

```
integer conversion resulted in truncation
integer conversion resulted in truncation
```

1. why do i get these warnings
2. how do i write my code, so that i dont get these warnings (without using #pragmas)

thanx,

i'm using IAR Compiler for 8051,

do you get similar warnings when compiling using other compilers?

Comment: +1 for not ignoring the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, arithmetics are performed at least at the size of `int`. That means, `~0xFC` will return an `int`. Even more, this value is `0xFF03` which is way beyond the range of `char` (signed or not).

Therefore, the assignment will give the two warnings. You could try

```
signed char sc = ~0xFC & 0xFF;
```

to see if the compiler knows that the result is within the range of `char` (gcc won't complain after adding the `& 0xFF`). You could also try to add an explicit cast:

```
signed char sc = (signed char)~0xFC;
// also possible:
// signed char sc = ~(signed char)0xFC;
```

or, as the value can be easily computed, why not just

```
signed char sc = 3;
```

Comment: ITYM `0xFFFFFF03` (@ 32 bits), and `3` in the last line.

Comment: @Paul: I'm not sure if the `int` is 32-bit, as 8051 is a 16-bit architecture, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: your answer is not correct in the sense that the `~` may well be applied to any integer type, in particular to `char` and then it returns a `char`. The unfortunate thing is that there is no such thing like a character constant literal in C, even the `'\0xx'` notation is `int`. So you'd have to do it as Jack proposes in his answer to obtain a character constant and then everything works fine.

Comment: indeed - it was the 03 rather than 04 that I was pointing out, but I see you've fixed that now.

Answer (score 6):

Because hexadecimal literals are considered int when written like you did `0xFC`.. to avoid the warning just cast them to truncate the number to just 1 byte:

```
~((char) 0xFC)
```

`0xFC` is considered `0x000000FC` on a 32 bit architecture, so when you apply not you obtain `0xFFFFFF03`, this means that when you assign this result to a char the 3 most relevant bytes are just discarded and the compiler warns you about it.